# Partial update of a subdocument with nodejs/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to set multiple properties on a (sub)document in one go with Mongoose? An example of what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have this schema:

```
var subSchema = new Schema({
    someField: String,
    someOtherField: String
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    fieldOne: String,
    subDocs: [subSchema]
})
```

Then I would like to do:

```
exports.updateMyDocument = function(req, res) {
    var parentDoc = req.parentDoc; // The parent document. Set by parameter resolver.
    var document = req.myDoc; // Sub document of parent. Set by parameter resolver.
    var partialUpdate = req.body; // updated fields sent as json and parsed by body parser
    // I know that the statement below doesn't work, it's just an example of what I would like to do.
    // Updating only the fields supplied in "partialUpdate" on the document
    document.update(partialUpdate); 
    parentDoc.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(500);
            return;
        }
        res.send(204);
    }); 
};
```

Normally, I could achieve this using the `$set` operator, but my problem is that `document` in this example is a subdocument (embedded schema) of `parentDoc`. So when I tried to do

```
Parent.update({_id: parentDoc._id, "subDocs._id": document._id}, 
    {$set: {"subDocs.$" : partialUpdate}}, 
    function(err, numAffected) {});
```

it replaced the subdocument instance identified by `subDocs._id`. Currently I have "solved" it by setting only fields manually, but I was hoping for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Build up a `$set` object programmatically based on the fields of `partialUpdate` to update just those fields using dot notation:

```
var set = {};
for (var field in partialUpdate) {
  set['subDocs.$.' + field] = partialUpdate[field];
}
Parent.update({_id: parentDoc._id, "subDocs._id": document._id}, 
    {$set: set}, 
    function(err, numAffected) {});
```

Comment: Yes, I did do that first. But I was hoping I didn't have to do that.

Comment: Accepting this, since it appears to be the only way to do it. In this case, is there any need for `hasOwnProperty` check, or is this not needed since it's a plain JSON object from the request body?

Comment: A slightly better way to loop the properties might be to use `Object.keys`, since it will only include "own properties" (although there probably won't be any other properties).

Comment: @NilsH It wouldn't hurt, but it's not needed if it's a simple JS object built from the request.  What you should think about though is whether you need to validate what fields you are including rather than blindly accepting the whole object.

Comment: Yes, that's implemented as schema validations right now. So in pair with input escaping, I hope that should be covered :)

Comment: @NilsH Mongoose's validation is much more limited with `update` calls than it is with `save`, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Wondering how multiple nested document can be handled...Parent, children, grandchildren type of setup?

Comment: I had no luck with my grandchildren in mongoose. Support is very limited, you'll have to loop through them manually. I restructured my schema to have only one level of nesting. E. g. Mongoose's parent.child.id('123') is very handy and works only at the first level until now.

Comment: From v3.9.3, update() takes 2 additional options: setDefaultsOnInsert and runValidators
@see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/1d8c3e96c7b11497d3325e9cf1f7ae66c9ee560e

Answer (score 7):

I've done different, in a REST application.

First, I have this route:

```
router.put('/:id/:resource/:resourceId', function(req, res, next) {
    // this method is only for Array of resources.
    updateSet(req.params.id, req.params.resource, req, res, next);
});
```

and the `updateSet()` method

```
function updateSet(id, resource, req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body;
    var resourceId = req.params.resourceId;

    Collection.findById(id, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) {
            rest.response(req, res, err);
        } else {
            var subdoc = collection[resource].id(resourceId);

            // set the data for each key
            _.each(data, function(d, k) {
              subdoc[k] = d;
            });

            collection.save(function (err, docs) {
              rest.response(req, res, err, docs);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The brilliant part is mongoose will validate the `data` if you define the `Schema` for this subdocument. This code will be valid for any resource of the document that is an Array. I'm not showing all my data for simplicity, but is a good practice to check for this situations and handle the response error properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign or extend embedded document.

```
    Doc.findOne({ _id: docId })
    .then(function (doc) {
      if (null === doc) {
        throw new Error('Document not found');
      }

      return doc.embeded.id(ObjectId(embeddedId));
    })
    .then(function(embeddedDoc) {
      if (null === embeddedDoc) {
        throw new Error('Embedded document not found');
      }

      Object.assign(embeddedDoc, updateData));
      return embeddedDoc.parent().save();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      //Do something
    });
```

And in this case you should be shure that _id is not assigning.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this in a slightly different manner without using the $set object. My approach is similar to Guilherme's but one difference is that I wrapped my method into the statics functionality so that it is easier to re-use throughout my application. Example below.

In CollectionSchema.js server model.

```
collectionSchema.statics.decrementsubdocScoreById = function decreasesubdoc (collectionId, subdocId, callback) {
  this.findById(collectionId, function(err, collection) {
    if (err) console.log("error finding collection");
    else {
      var subdoc = collection.subdocs.filter(function (subdoc) {
        return subdoc._id.equals(subdocId);
      })[0];

      subdoc.score -= 1;

      collection.save(callback);
    }
  });
};
```

In Server Controller

```
Collection.decrementsubdocScoreById(collectionId, subdocId, function  (err, data) {
  handleError(err);
  doStuffWith(data);
});
```