# How do i save a sub document's array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've seen a lot of examples, how to update an array, like this one
[Mongoose find/update subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument)
and this one
[Partial update of a subdocument with nodejs/mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874750/partial-update-of-a-subdocument-with-nodejs-mongoose)

but my objective is to update a specific field, for example in a Form, where user enters data.

I'm using ejs for templating.

Here's the code

For clarity , here is User's Schema

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   resume: {
     education: [{ type: String}],
   }

});
```

Routing code

```
router.post('/update-resume', function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser) {

        // Take a look over here, how do I update an item in this array?
        if (req.body.education) foundUser.resume.education.push(req.body.education);

        foundUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('message', 'Successfully update a resume');
            return res.redirect('/update-resume')
        });
    });

});
```

If you take a look at the code above, my objective is to query a user data which is resume, and update its current value.

Code for the front end

```
<form role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="education">Education:</label>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < user.resume.education.length; i++) { %>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="education" id="education" value="<%= user.resume.education[i] %>">
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Frontend code does work, it iterate in each `user.resume.education` array, and show all the values in the array. But how do I update it?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `.push()` to the education array, mongoose don't know that this field has changed, you need to specify it with the `markModified()` function so mongoose will know that this field has changed, so, after you push to the education array use:

`foundUser.markModified('resume.education');`

and then use the `save()` function

**UPDATE:**

```
router.post('/update-resume', function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser) {

        // Take a look over here, how do I update an item in this array?
        if (req.body.education) foundUser.resume.education.push(req.body.education);

        foundUser.markModified('resume.education'); // <-- ADDITION

        foundUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('message', 'Successfully update a resume');
            return res.redirect('/update-resume')
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Check out the gist, for somehow, I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: and second how does body parser will know which req.body belong to which index?

Comment: you need to use the same code you showed in your question, and just add the markModified row between the `push` and the `save` actions

Comment: Just to let you know, I did what you did, and it keeps pushing a new value to the array instead of updating it. Does it have anything to do with the frontend or backend?

Comment: of course it will, you have a String array, how you think it will update the value? each element inside your education array is just a string, not an object with an ID, my suggestion, read about the population here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, this is what I think you meant