# Mongoose doesn't save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a save() in a post route, that doesn't actually save anything.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```js
router.post('/addSchemaField/:id',(req,res,next)=>{

mongooseDynamic.addSchemaField(Profile, req.body.table+"."+req.body.name, {type : [String], default : ""});


Profile.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {

  if (err) return next(err);
  
  post[req.body.table][req.body.name][4] = req.body.typ;
  
  console.log(post[req.body.table][req.body.name]);
  
  post.markModified('post[req.body.table][req.body.name][4]');
  
  post.save(function(err, upPost){
    res.send(upPost);
  });
});  
res.end();
});
```

Comment: where mongoose operations which they must save

Comment: Perhaps you meant the actual subdocument dynamic path as ``post.markModified(`${post[req.body.table]}.${[req.body.name]}`);``?

Comment: @chridam Thank you! that worked, though just one time... any other ideas ?

Comment: Try ``post.markModified(`${req.body.table}.${req.body.name}`);``

Comment: @chridam Still no luck, but I noticed that if I try to console.log "upPost" it is undefined in the save() function, which I also don't understand

Comment: You could try to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33327652/122005)

Comment: @chridam Okay, so I got it working now by just updating the whole table (i.e deleting ${req.body.name}) ! thank you for your continued support, would not have been able to work this out otherwise!