# how to update nested object of mongoose document for only provided keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I am going to update some fields of mongoose document according to provided keys.
For example,
When we present mongoose document in json.

```
user: {
  address: {
    city: "city"
    country: "country"
  }
}
```

And update params is given like this.

```
address: {
   city: "city_new"
}
```

when I run the mongoose api like this.

```
let params = {
   address: {
      city: "city_new"
   }
}
User.set(param)
```

It replace whole address object and final result is

```
user: {
  address: {
    city: "city_new"
  }
}
```

it just replace address field, but I want to only update city field.
This is desired result.

```
user: {
  address: {
    city: "city_new"
    country: "country"
  }
}
```

How to do this in mongoose?

When nested object has more complex hierarchy, how can we solve this without manually indicate field like `address.city.field1.field2. ...`

Thanks

Comment: You have to use .Dot notation to update nested fields else move them to root level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When nested object has more complex hierarchy, how can we solve this
>   without manually indicate field like address.city.field1.field2.

As most answers intimated, you have to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) to update embedded documents and to answer your above question, use the following helper method which applies recursion to convert a given object to its dot notation representation:

```js
function convertToDotNotation(obj, newObj={}, prefix="") {

  for(let key in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
          convertToDotNotation(obj[key], newObj, prefix + key + ".");
      } else {
          newObj[prefix + key] = obj[key];
      }
  }

  return newObj;
}


let params = {
   address: {
      city: {
         location: {
            street: "new street"
         }
      }  
   }
};

const dotNotated = convertToDotNotation(params);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dotNotated, null, 4));
```

Comment: This issue is a duplicate of many others, but the most common solution I've seen is to use the 'flat' npm package and call something like:
`Model.update(filter, flat(update))`

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
let params = {
   "address.city": "city_new"
}
User.set(param)
```

In the documentation on [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) you'll also find the following remark:

> To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot
>   notation.

Comment: yes, but I am not going to indicate fields by dot.
so if we use more deep hierarchy, we don't have to use dot operator.

Comment: There is no other way that I'm aware of. Kindly see the following links, too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874750/partial-update-of-a-subdocument-with-nodejs-mongoose
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290621/how-do-i-partially-update-an-object-in-mongodb-so-the-new-object-will-overlay
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21094